# index.php shown up in every link

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

my problem is that my link shows (index.php) in every link like this

```
(www.mysite.com/index.php/postname)
```

and i want to show it like this

```
 (www.mysite.com/postname)
```

but i want to remove that (index.php) from my links so how to do that?

i m using 
(iis) 7.5 and (wordpress) 4.01

i try so many  things but did not work so how to solve it?

and i cant also see web.config
but i can see (wp.config) so are they same?

Comment: IIS wouldnt do that, check `wp.config` thats for wordpress. I dont know if windows has htaccess, but this is for sure from wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log into wordpress admin and go to permalinks and change

Custom Structure to: `/%postname%/`

Do not add the domain or `index.php`

if your'e running IIS you need to follow instructions on this link:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite
```

or you can just
add web.config file to the root folder (where the WP install is) containing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
         <rules>
            <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url=".*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then you can adjust your permalinks to your custom setup in the admin panel.